# Looping through subfolders in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code from another question and am trying to customize it.

I get error message

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed.

I want to use the path to the main folder to iterate through all of the (sub)folders within that folder. Those subfolders do not contain further subfolders.

I want to open every Excel file that has the substring "-WB_" in the file name, and make edits (the edits seen in this code are just a placeholder to see if it works). I use InStr to try and determine if CurrFile.Name has "-WB_" in it.

One thought I have is that CurrFile.Name is not giving a string, so when I try to use Workbooks.Open it is not working.

I took out my real pathName and replaced it with "Path to Main Folder" to protect my real name.

```
Sub LoopSubfoldersAndFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim subfolders As Object
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim CurrFile As Object
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim pathName As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("PATH TO MAIN FOLDER")
    Set subfolders = folder.subfolders
    pathName = "PATH TO MAIN FOLDER"

    For Each subfolders In subfolders

        Set CurrFile = subfolders.Files

        For Each CurrFile In CurrFile
            fileName = CurrFile.Name
            If InStr(CurrFile.Name, "-WB_") Then
                Workbooks.Open (pathName & fileName)
                Workbooks(CurrFile.Name).Sheets(1).Range("a1:a20") = "Excel"
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
            End If
        Next

    Next

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set subfolders = Nothing

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you place `Debug.Print fileName` before the `Workbooks.Open`, you'll be able to see the values in the immediate window.

Comment: Also, wouldn't you need to add the subfolder in there like `Workbooks.Open (pathName & 
subfolders.Name & fileName)` (or the equivalent)?

Comment: @Mistella where would I be able to see the values in the immediate windwo when I use 'Debug.Print fileName'? (sorry, i'm really new at VBA. when I typed this into the line above, I just continued getting the same error with no new info popping up)

Comment: updating my code to Workbooks.Open (pathName & subfolders.Name & "\" & fileName) worked! Thank you

Comment: @A.C. You would get `Debug.Print` messages in the Immediate Window, which is normally at the bottom of the VBA window. Alternatively, you can use `MsgBox()` and get a popup message.